# How convert dynamic html page to pdf in django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, pdf

1) I parse some pages to get information.
2) As it information hard to detach, i install it to html page and make it beautiful with custom css.
3) Then i try to convert it to pdf to provide it to customers.

But all pdf-convectors ask for certain url, or file and so on. For example:

```
def parse(request):
        done = csrf(request)
        if request.POST:
            USERNAME = request.POST.get('logins', '')
            PASSWORD = request.POST.get('password', '')
            dialogue_url = request.POST.get('links', '')
            total_pages = int(request.POST.get('numbers', ''))
            news = []
            news.extend(parse_one(USERNAME, PASSWORD, dialogue_url, total_pages))
            contex = {
                        "news" : news,
                    }
            done.update(contex)

        pageclan = render(request, 'marketing/parser.html', done)

        # create an API client instance
        client = pdfcrowd.Client(*** ***)

        # convert a web page and store the generated PDF to a variable. That is doesn't work. Convertor doesn't support such url.
        pdf = client.convertURI('pageclan')

         # set HTTP response headers
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
        response["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0"
        response["Accept-Ranges"] = "none"
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=jivo_log.pdf"

        # send the generated PDF
        response.write(pdf)
        return response
```

Is there any tools, that can work fine?

Answer (score 0):

From [PDFCrowd Python API documentation](http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-python/):

> You can also convert raw HTML code, just use the `convertHtml()` method instead of `convertURI()`:
>
> `pdf = client.convertHtml("<head></head><body>My HTML Layout</body>")`

which means that you can modify your code to use the `convertHtml` method with your rendered page (which is an HTML string):

```
pdf = client.convertHtml(pageclan.content)
```

Comment: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'encode'
html = html.encode('utf-8') seems it ask for utf-8 or something

Comment: @SergeyBakotin Yes, you need to use the `content` only. See updated answer.